# Android RecyclerView - Class is not abstract and does not implement abstract base class member

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I got this:

```
class RecentAdapter(private val context: Context, private val videolist: MutableList<Videos>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecentAdapter.ViewHolder>(){

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val video = videolist[position]

        holder.title.text = video.title

        holder.remove.setOnClickListener {

            videolist.removeAt(holder.adapterPosition)
            notifyItemRemoved(holder.adapterPosition)

        }

    }

    override fun getItemCount() = videolist.size

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.videoview, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    class ViewHolder(itemView: View?) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView!!){

        val title = itemView!!.videoviewTitle!!
        val remove = itemView!!.videoviewRemove!!
        val like = itemView!!.videoviewLike!!

    }
}
```

I get the error:

```
Class 'RecentAdapter' is not abstract and does not implement abstract base class member public abstract fun onBindViewHolder(@NonNull p0: RecentAdapter.ViewHolder, p1: Int): Unit defined in android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.Adapter
```

on `class RecentAdapter`

And

```
'onBindViewHolder' overrides nothing
```

And

Unresolved reference on `title` and `remove`

Can someone help me?

Comment: Your IDE can generate methods you need to implement on a class that is trying to implement an interface or abstract class. Learn to use the IDE. If IntelliJ/AndroidStudio , try Alt+Enter while the cursor is on top of your class name, `RecentAdapter`.

Answer (score 1):

Change `onBindViewHolder()`'s signature to this:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int)
```

The 1st argument's type is `ViewHolder` and not `RecyclerView.ViewHolder`

Comment: It works! Thanks! The thing is it worked this way before!! I'm serious, I got it from a tutorial where it ofc also works and it worked in my other app. I'm rly so sick and tired of the whole overengineered harder than is needs to be annying piece of crap android..

Comment: You will get used to such (harmless) errors that can be fixed easily. Android development is much more complicated than this.

Answer (score 0):

For the first question:

You are not overriding the right method. In your constructor, you are declaring that the `ViewHolder` to use is `RecentAdapter.ViewHolder`, but your `onBindViewHolder` references the generic `RecyclerView.ViewHolder`. To fix this, simply change

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
```

to

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecentAdapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
```

For the second question, I am not sure what the error is with the given files. Make sure you that there are views with Ids `videoViewTitle` and `videoViewRemove` within the `videoview` layout file to start?